# IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am facing above mentioned exception while sending json object to server, 
Here is my complete code.

RegisterModelQ.java

```
public class RegisterModelQ {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    private String mobile;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("device_token")
    private String deviceToken;
    @SerializedName("device_type")
    private String deviceType;

    public RegisterModelQ(String name, String mobile, String password, String device_type, String device_token) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.password = password;
        this.deviceToken= device_token;
        this.deviceType = device_type;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/log-in")
Call<LoginModelR> getLoginAPI(LoginModelQ loginModel);
```

APIClient.java

```
public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(EndPoints.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();


    return retrofit;
```

And my call

```
@Override
public void registerCall(RegisterModelQ registerModelQ) {
    view.showProgress();
    APIInterface apiService = APIClient.getRetrofit().create(APIInterface.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String string = Utils.getGson().toJson(registerModelQ);
    try {
         jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Call<RegisterModelR> call = apiService.getRegisterAPI(jsonObject);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterModelR>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RegisterModelR> call, Response<RegisterModelR> response) {
            view.hideProgress();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                view.changeView(new DashboardFragment());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RegisterModelR> call, Throwable t) {
            Utils.logD(TAG, "Errrr: " + t.getMessage());
            view.hideProgress();
        }
    });

}
```

Error log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
    for method APIInterface.getRegisterAPI
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:351)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
    at $Proxy0.getRegisterAPI(Unknown Source)
    at com.codingnation.shoingfest.ui.register.RegisterImpl.registerCall(RegisterImpl.java:61)
    at com.codingnation.shoingfest.ui.register.RegisterImpl.validateFields(RegisterImpl.java:46)
    at com.codingnation.shoingfest.ui.register.RegisterFragment$1.onClick(RegisterFragment.java:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have found many questions related to mine but did not get my error solved, 
plus what if I want to send Java object to API.
Should I implement this in PHP on server side?

Comment: There is getLoginAPI in your ApiInterface class but you use getRegisterAPI in your call.

Comment: Please post `LoginModelQ`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

#### Step 1:

```
    public JSONObject getJsonObject(Object object) {
        ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            String jsonStr = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(object);
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                return jsonObject;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

#### Step 2:

```
    APIInterface apiService = APIClient.getRetrofit().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<RegisterModelR> call = apiService.getLoginAPI(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                getJsonObject(registerModelQ).toString()));
```

#### Step 3:

```
    @POST("user/log-in")
    Call<LoginModelR> getLoginAPI(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

Good luck.